# Unable to login to Afresco share after changing the port no

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I changed the port from 8086 (which was working fine) to 8085 in server.xml file. After restarting the tomcat-server, I was able to get the login page by hitting http://localhost:8085/share however, when I try to login I get an Authentication fail error.

If I change the port no back to 8086 it works fine and I am able to login.

I am not sure what is the problem here as I also tried by changing the port no in alfresco-global.properties file and share-config-custom.xml. However, the issue still exists.

Answer (score 1):

There are some configuration in **share-config-custom.xml** file for host and port.Those are used for connecting alfresco repository.You need to change in that as well otherwise it wonnt be able to connect with alfresco.

Comment: Yes.. I have made changes in share-config-custom.xml file as well. I still get authentication fail error.

Comment: your alfresco is successfully getting started.check log of alfresco server?Do you have share and alfresco on differrent tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the Tomcat connector port, AJP and RMI ports too. Otherwise it may conflict during a shutdown.